# How can I create a foreign key with Index in one single create table statement? (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried to create a new table (tableB) with a foreign key constraint to another table (tableA) and just wondering if I can create along with this all constraints and indexes needed. My goal would be to have a single `create table` statement with no need of an `alter table…` statement afterwards and no other `create index…` statement. Is this possible? Thanks for any hint in advance :)

```
create table tableA
(
   id number
 , constraint tableApk primary key (id)
);

create table tableB
(
   id number
 , constraint tableBfk foreign key (id) references tableA (id)
                       on delete cascade
                       using index (
                         create index tableBfkidx on tableB (id)
                       )
);
```

Comment: It's all about `tableB`, not `tableA`… and for primary key I can use `using index (…)` – just wondered why this is not possible for the foreign key.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That isn't allowed. [Per the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses002.htm#i1002419) a ***using_index_clause*** can only be specified for unique or primary constraints.

Best of luck.

Comment: I mistakenly wanted to use `using index (…)` as for the primary key for my foreign key as well… did maybe overlook that comment in the documentation. Thanks!